Why is the tradition of Easter "Friday to Sunday" when passover was on wednesday?
Since we know that Yeshua was born during the time of Herod, and Herod died shortly after the lunar eclipse on January 10th, 1 BC, we can use this as a reference point for the birth and death of Yeshua.
In Matthew 12:40, Yeshua mentions being in the grave for "three days and three nights," just as Jonah was in the belly of the fish. Celebrating from Friday to Sunday does not fulfill this timeframe. Yeshua, adhering to Torah, would have begun his ministry at the age of 30, around 31 AD. He was crucified the next Passover.
Why follow a timeline known to be incorrect? The death of Christ aligns with Passover, allowing us to accurately date and celebrate His sacrifice on Passover each year.
In 31 AD, Passover fell on a Wednesday, and Yeshua was crucified that day. He rose early on Saturday morning (the Sabbath), fulfilling the "three days and three nights" prophecy. The Council of Laodicea shifted the focus away from the Sabbath, a commandment unrelated to the "New" Covenant but still a commandment.
Dismissing one of the Ten Commandments makes little sense. Avoiding shared observances with Jews is not a valid reason. Celebrating with symbols like bunnies and eggs, or Christmas trees, mixes pagan traditions with Christian observances, deviating from the Word of God and adhering to human traditions instead of scripture.
Both Christmas and Easter are man-made holidays. According to Genesis 1, a new day begins at sunset, a principle that should remain unchanged as God's Law is eternal.

The question is why is the tradition of Easter "Friday to Sunday" when passover is on a wednesday?

where is the question?

Welcome to the site, Location Delta. I have looked in vain for any question. This site is for asking a question. What is your question? Further, twice you state, "Sunday is not" - but, not WHAT? If you go to this link, you will be guided in how to ask acceptable questions on this site. As you have not asked a question, this is likely to be closed down - unless you can state a question you seek an answer to. : christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

To those asking what the question is, please understand that this is clearly not native english. The expression of the question is "Friday to Sunday is not three days". (Different sentence structure) but the body is a rambling mess of concepts from a different language.

I've seen similar contextual references mid sentence before, this is difficult to read. Location Delta, can you please attempt to clearly tell us what your question is? I'm starting to understand the body of the text... oh boy

I've jumped ahead and attempted to rewrite everything into english proper. I cannot fix the way the format is jumping around. But I believe I've made the question clear.

Christs ministry was prophesied in Daniel 9:26&27 to last 3.5 years (cut off in the middle of the week). I think scholars believe he died around A.D 33/34 because of Daniel 9. Also the 3 days are traditionally counting parts of days. Friday (the day he died) = 1 day, Saturday(in the grave) = 2 day, Sunday = 3 day. The text says he will rise on the 3rd day. That's my understanding of it.

This question is similar to: How did Christians get from the biblical feast of Passover to Easter sunday?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The difference between the two questions is this one is about why there was a change to Easter from Passover, while the other question is about how there was a change from Passover to Easter.  It may be a fine distinction that basically is between uniformity and enforcement, but IMO the difference is present.

Couple of things.
Passover floats each year based on the solar/lunar calendar.  The 14th of Nisan (Passover) has never been fixed to a Wednesday (or Thursday, Friday, etc).  It is similar to Christmas, it is always dated on the 25th of December, but the day floats.
There is a mistake to translate "heart of the earth" to mean solely "grave".  It isn't.

For as Jonas was three days and three nights in the whale's belly; so shall the Son of man be three days and three nights in the heart of the earth. Mt 12:40

This 3 day and 3 night sequence refers to this prophecy.

For God is my King of old, working salvation in the midst [heart] of the earth. Psa 74:12

The word translated midst is qereb.  Gesenius 2b the heart.  The point is the phrase refers to the whole period as Christ said from sufferings to glory.

To whom also he shewed himself alive after his passion by many infallible proofs, being seen of them forty days, and speaking of the things pertaining to the kingdom of God: Acts 1:3

Passion is a noun, the whole sequence.

"to suffer," is used as a noun, in the aorist infinitive with the article, and translated "passion" in Act 1:3, of the suffering of Christ at Calvary. Vines Expository Dictionary of New Testament Words

A crucifixion, death, and burial (based on the OP assumptions) on a Wednesday would begin the count.  Wednesday 1, Thursday 2, Friday 3, Saturday 4.  Doesn't work and is incorrect.

OP: The question is why is the tradition of Easter "Friday to Sunday" when passover is on a wednesday?

As mentioned, Passover is never fixed to a particular day.  And Christ clearly was not crucified on a Wednesday.  The Friday to Sunday tradition established at Nicea was based on a desire to observe His passion uniformly.  It was confusing otherwise.

Our Saviour has left us only one festal day of our redemption, that is to say, of his holy passion, and he desired [to establish] only one Catholic Church.  Think, then, how unseemly it is, that on the same day some should be fasting whilst others are seated at a banquet; and that after Easter, some should be rejoicing at feasts, whilst others are still observing a strict fast.  For this reason, a Divine Providence wills that this custom should be rectified and regulated in a uniform way; and everyone, I hope, will agree upon this point. On the Keeping of Easter

Without going into detail, Rome was observing the Friday death and burial to Sunday resurrection tradition, which is the 15th through 17th of Nisan.  It wanted the rest of Christendom to follow its custom.

OP: Why follow a timeline known to be incorrect? The death of Christ aligns with Passover, allowing us to accurately date and celebrate His sacrifice on Passover each year.

In this day and age, people are certainly free to observe the 3 days and 3 nights in any way they want.  Just note, however, that observations aren't what saves us.
EDIT TO ADD
To clarify Esther's fast of 3 nights and 3 days (4:16), that's what she instructs in this life and death situation.  No one is going to end their fast before the 3 nights and 3 days is up.  The fast began at sunset, beginning night one and day one.  Sunset, night two and day two.  Sunset night three and day three.  On day three, she goes to the king (5:1).  It doesn't say she broke her fast.  It does say the king and Haman ate (5:5).  On the next day, she will prepare another banquet and reveal her request.  Haman then invites her to join them (5:12, 7:1).  That night four the king is troubled and finds out about Mordecai.  On day four, they sit at banquet, which is called the second day (7:12) counting day 3 as day 1 and this second banquet on day 2.  This is when Esther's fast is broke.  Esther reveals the information as a flood from a failed dam.
The point is, while some say that 3 days and 3 nights is always a Jewish idiom, it is absolutely not in this life and death case.  Nor is it an idiom in Jonah's case.  Likewise, it is not an idiom in Jesus' case.  But, until one understands that "heart of the earth" is not an idiom for grave, but instead for Christ's whole passion period from sufferings to glory over 3 nights and 3 days, then most likely this will be ignored.

That's a very clear answer to a very unclear question! so +1. I would just mention that the matter of fixing the date for what has become known as "Easter" resulted in many deaths, such was the controversy. However, that may be beside the point here, as the OP seems to be more concerned about the date of Passover/last supper being a Wednesday night, with Christ's death on Thursday (which would make 3 days in the grave by his count, if the resurrection was Saturday morning.) It's still  a can of worms!

I would have gone into exhaustive detail about how Pascha is handled, and how it actually is correct, and how days were counted "night day night day" not "day night day night" like they are today. +1

@Wyrsa Yes, the day begins at sunset.  Sunset, end of one day and start of next day.  Sunset, night, day; Sunset, night, day until the end of time.  I explained why the idea that the heart of the earth (Mt. 12:40) is a reference to the whole period that Jesus tells us many times, it is from sufferings to glory.  It is not from into the grave through out of the grave.  As the idea shifted from slay the lamb at sunset to begin the 14th Nisan (Exo 12:6, Lev 23:5, Num 9:5) to slay the lamb in the afternoon of the 14th (see Josephus and Philo) the whole clarity of what really happened disappeared.

Esther in 5:1 "put on her royal clothes".  When Jews fasted they typically put on "sackcloth with ashes".  "There was great mourning among the Jews, and fasting, and weeping and wailing; and many lay in sackcloth & ashes" (Esther 4:3).  The context also shows she fasted before going into the King's presence. Your argument that three days and three nights includes the suffering in Gethsemane seems arbitrary & contrived: who would have thought that the antitype of the type described as "Jonah in the whale's belly" would include some time alive in a garden?  Linking Acts 1:3 is also arbitrary.

If there had been an intention to link the story of Jonah with Psalm 74:12 then in Jonah 2:3 it would have used the same hebrew word for "midst of the seas" as "heart of the earth" in Ps 74:12. Ps 74:12 uses "qereb" - centre, heart;  Jonah 2:3 uses "lebab".  You haven't given any evidence Matthew 12:40, which is in Greek not Hebrew, has anything to do with Ps 74:12.  You would need to quote the Greek in the Septuagint for Ps 74:12.  But in any case, Matt 12:40 is clearly refering to Christ being enclosed in the centre of the earth 3 days and 3 nights, i.e. in the grave 3 days and 3 nights

Yes, Esther put on royal clothes at 5:1 otherwise they would not have let her in (Est 4:2.  It wasn't the end of her fast of 3 nights/days, but to gain access.  How was Jonah in the belly (alive and dead).  Also, not arbitrary: "The sufferings of Our Lord, which culminated in His death upon the cross, seem to have been conceived of as one inseparable whole from a very early period. Even in the Acts of the Apostles (i, 3) St. Luke speaks of those to whom Christ "shewed himself alive after his passion" (meta to mathein autou). " New Advent.

Why is the tradition of Easter 'from Friday to Sunday' when the crucifixion happened on Wednesday?
Here, I shall argue that the crucifixion did happen on Friday, 14th Nisan.
John 19:31 says the day was "parascevi", Preparation. Even today in the Greek language parascevi means both "preparation" and "Friday".  It means preparation for the sabbath.
And it was the day before the sabbath, even "a high day" because it was both a Sabbath Saturday and a Sabbath being 15th Nisan, the first day of unleavened bread, Leviticus 23:6,7.
14th Nisan was a Friday in both AD 30 and AD 33.
Our Lord's earthly ministry lasted  for over two years, at least.  This can be seen by examining the mention of Passovers in John's Gospel.
The first Passover is found in John 2:13 and 23.  This Passover was shortly after his ministry had begun.
The second Passover is in John 6:4.
The third Passover is the one at his crucifixion (eg 11:55).
These three Passovers mean our Lord's earthly ministry was a minimum of just over two years.
Another feast is mentioned by John, but we cannot know if it was a Passover, 5:1.  But we do not need to know to build a timeline for our Lord's ministry.  (Other feasts mentioned in John are the Feast of Tabernacles/ Booths, 7:2, and the Feast of Dedication (of the Temple), 10:22.)
In Luke 3:1 we are told that John the Baptist's ministry began in "the fifthteenth year of Tiberius Caesar". As Hold to the Rod shows in his videos, we have two double-dated coins which prove the year from which his reign is dated, either from the death of Augustus, or the first New Year's Day after his death. Caesar Augustus died on 19th August AD 14. (Whether he had a coregency is irrelevant, the coins show his reign is dated from the death of Augustus.) Either way, it means, given the length of our Lord's ministry was at least 2 years, that the crucifixion could not possibly have happened as early as AD 30.

Tiberius was named head of the Roman state on 17th September AD 14. His 15th year [the start of John's ministry, as mentioned in Luke 3:1] would have been 17th Sept AD 28 to 16th Sept AD 29, or if official Roman Regnal years were intended 1st Jan AD 29 to 31 Dec AD 29. ("From Abraham to Paul - a Biblical chronology" by Andrew Steinmann, 2011, page 219)

Our Lord was about 30 years old at his baptism, Luke 3:23, and he was born before the death of Herod the Great. Herod's death was between a lunar eclipse and a Passover falling at least 41 days after the eclipse.  This points to the death of Herod falling after the (Total) lunar eclipse of 10th Jan 1 BC, not the (Partial) lunar eclipse of 13th Mar 4 BC.
Another evidence is the testimony of Phlegon of Tralles. He wrote that there were three hours of darkness during the daytime in the 4th year of the 202nd Olympiad.  An Olympic Games happened every 4 years in Greece with the 1st one happening in 776 BC.  The calculation to convert to Julian / Gregorian years is thus:
-777 + ((olympiad value - 1) * 4) + year within olympiad. And where value is positive add one more year (because there was no year zero between 1 BC and AD 1).
The Olympic games happened in June, July, each year.  The 4th year of the 202nd Olympiad works out at AD 32.  This marks the start of the year in June-July.  The year thus was from July AD 32 to June AD 33. And of course, during this year was Passover AD 33, when 14th Nisan was a Friday.
Julius Africanus quotes a portion of Phlegon's writings which is no longer extant, which says these 3 hours happened at the time of the Full Moon.  Clearly,  this secular author, Phlegon, writing in South West Turkey, is noting the 3 hours of darkness at the time of the crucifixion.  It is also said it happened "from the sixth hour to the ninth hour" exactly as recorded in the scriptures, Luke 23:44,45.  (The Greeks divided the hours of daylight into 12 portions, the first hour being the first hour after sunrise. In winter the hours were thus slightly shorter than in summer: at Passover (and autumnal equinox) the hours were very close to exactly one of our hours.)
Tertullian also writes about it, mentioning the writings of Roman historian Thallus, who is generally believed to have been writing about AD 50. Thallus writings on this are no longer extant, but Tertullian's are. According to Tertullian, Thallus does not deny the existence of our Lord, nor the event of the 3 hours of darkness; Thallus, being opposed to Christanity, attempts to explain away the 3 hours not deny them. Tertullian further writes that the 3 hours are also recorded in the Official Archives of the City of Rome.
You can read about this, free online, in Daniel's Seventy Weeks by Derek Walker, appendix 4, "The day the sun stopped shining".  Derek is Pastor at Oxford Baptist Church.
The explanation of "three days and three nights" by the OP does not work.  True, it is three nights, but it is not three days. For an explanation of the phrase see my answer here, Was the Last Supper not the Passover meal?

That's an important  point about the OPs 'count' still not adding up to 3 days and 3 nights. That link to your answer on the last supper and Passover significant.

You still haven't explained 3 nights?Which night is the first one in the grave and which one is the 3rd? I have read both of your posts (this and the linked one), you say the last supper was Wednesday night and that he was crucified friday. This to me suggests a spiritual death on Thursday night in the garden when he was wearing blood and two physical death nights (Friday and Satuday)?

@adam - I have explained it in the answer which is linked at the bottom of my answer, Was the Last Supper not the Passover meal. I really don't want to repeat it here.  The reason for 3 days and 3 nights is really very well known, and is given multiple times in Scripture.

@adam - see for instance 1 Kings 12v5 and 12v12.. the king said come back after 3 days, but they came back on the 3rd day "as the king had appointed". On the third day means after 3 days according to Jewish idiom throughout the Bible. "After 2 days" however means exactly what we mean, the idiom only begins for the 3rd day and continues for more than the 3rd. So John 20:26 "after 8 days again" to us means after 7 days, ie the following Sunday. And Hosea 6:2 is Hebrew poetry because it mentions the same day in two different ways: after 2 days (no idiom) he will revive, the 3rd (with idiom)

@adam - the explanation of third day is best given in Luke 13:32 and Leviticus 7:15-17.  The strange reality is "after 2 days" (no idiom) means exactly the same as "after 3 days" (with idiom)

@adam - "three days and three nights" is the same idiom as in Esther 4:16.  The fast ended after two nights because she went to the king on the third day  (Esther 5:1).  Sorry, I must have been a million miles away when I read your post, I missed your comment that the third night was in gethsemane.  There was no third night at all.  We'll all be at sixes and sevens until we realize "three nights and three days" is an idiom meaning a continuous period involving a portion of time (however small) from three consecutive 24 hour days.  And when everyone accepts that I'll be on cloud nine.

@ Andrew...yes I already explained the appropriate understanding of "parts of days". It is the statement of 3 nights that im focusing on. You say there is no 3rd night, amd yet references are made to Jonah 3 days and nights in the fish...I dont think why has been explained well. I highlighted that believe the third night is one of spiritual suffering in the garden of gethsemene ...Luke 22 says, and being in anguish he prayed more earnestly

@adam - "three days and three nights" means a continuous period involving portions of three consecutive 24 hour days. It thus means a portion of the last hours of (24 hour) day 1, all 24 hours of day 2, and a portion of the beginning of (24 hour) day 3.  The Jews didn't say a 24 hour day, they spoke of "a day and a night" to mean a 24 hour period.

And they spoke of this as an "onah" and a portion of an onah could be understood as the whole of it, as described in the quote of the Talmud in my answer to Was the Last Supper not a Passover meal?

Excellent explanation, and if I could give you a second up-vote for sheer patience, I would!

The tradition of Easter is Friday to Sunday because the gospels clearly state that he died on a Friday (Matt. 27:62, Mk. 15:42, Lk. 23:54, Jn. 19:31), and that the first day of the week was the third day from the time he was crucified (Lk. 24:1, 21).
Your confusion expressed in your general dissertation, if that's the right thing to call it, is based on grossly unsubstantiated suppositions. The evidence does not support Herod the Great dying in 1 BCE. Nor does it support Christ's crucifixion in 31 CE, or on the actual day of the Passover, though this last point, at least, is commonly accepted in academia, whether or not it is correct.
That's your answer in a nutshell, just so the answer is clearly stated. The gospels say he died on a Friday and rose on Sunday. That's why the tradition of Easter is Friday to Sunday.
Proofs:
Three gospels clearly state that the Last Supper occurred following the afternoon of the fourteenth day of the month. It was the first-most day of unleavened bread. It was the day when the passover was slain. And two disciples, Peter and John, were sent to prepare the Passover, which they did. (Matt. 26:17-21, Mk. 14:12-18, Lk. 22:7-15)
Jesus was crucified the next day, which by default would be the 15th day of the month. There are many who have difficulty accepting this plainly stated fact of scripture, but three gospels testify to it.
The confusion with John, that the priests wouldn't enter Pilate's palace to avoid defilement in order to eat the Passover, is misunderstood. John is speaking of the Hagigah, or the Passover of the 15th, a festive offering that is not only obligatory, but literally referred to as the Passover, both in scripture and in rabbinic literature (Deut. 16:2, bPesach 70a-b). And while there can only be one day that can be considered the “first” day of unleavened bread, there were two feasts referred to as the Passover. Furthermore, a person defiled by a dead body can still purify themselves to eat the Passover sacrifice. It's the hagigah that they are disbarred from if they become defiled (bPesach 80a).
For the crucifixion to have happened on any day other than Friday would require the crucifixion to have occurred on the 14th so that the holiday sabbath of the 15th (cf. Ex. 12:16, Lev. 23:4-7, Num. 28:16-26, Lev. 23:1-3) would fulfill the sabbath requirement of the gospel chronology. The 16th was only a sabbath if it fell on a Saturday. Interestingly enough, Matthew makes the circumlocutive statement that the day after the crucifixion was the day that followed the day of the preparation. Rather than calling it the sabbath, which might have created some confusion in a week that had two sabbaths due to the holiday, he instead referred to the sabbath in a roundabout way by calling it the day after Friday.
As for Herod, a death later than 2 BCE is impossible relative to the facts we have. To get to 1 BCE, it would require his reign to begin later than it did. We have documented and definitive evidence that his reign began in 40 BCE and 37 BCE respectively.
We know that Herod traveled to Samosata to aid Antony in his campaign against Antiochus, and we know beyond dispute that the siege at Samosata occurred in the summer of 38 BCE, and was isolated to that single year (App. B Civ. 5.93, 95; Dio Cass. 49.22.1-49.23.1, 49.21, 49.22.1-2, 49.23.1; Plut. Ant. 34.1-4; Plut. Ant. 34; Val. Max. 6.9.9; Plin. HN 7.135; Gell. NA 15.4; Joseph AJ 14.439-447, 14.434; Joseph. BJ 1.323; Dio Cass. 49.23.1; Ov. Fast. 6.465; Acta Triumphorum, CIL 1². Ventidius defeated Pacorus in 38 BCE. He then commenced a siege on Samosata, but was relieved by Antony and sent to Rome where he was voted a triumph, which is well attested — P. Ventidius P. f. pro cos. ex Tauro monte et Partheis v k. Decemb. — These events occurred in the consulship of App. Claudius and C. Norbanus, placing the siege at Samosata firmly in 38 BCE, and the siege at Jerusalem likewise firmly in 37 BCE beyond any dispute.).
Once Antiochus surrendered, Herod immediately returned to Judaea that same year at the conclusion of the siege, and he returned early enough to prosecute a considerable campaign before being forced to pause and to delay any military action against Jerusalem due to the severity of the winter of 38/37 BCE (Joseph AJ 14.447-61; Joseph BJ 1.321). But as soon as the worst of the winter had passed, he began his siege of Jerusalem. The siege was five months long, beginning in the month of Shebat. Jerusalem was then taken in Sivan, the third month of the Jewish ecclesiastical year, putting his conquest of Jerusalem solidly in the late spring of 37 BCE. (Joseph. AJ 14.465-466, Joseph. BJ 1.351, Knowing that the five-month siege of Jerusalem ended in “the third month,” or Sivan, this siege began at some point in Shebat during the winter of 38/37 BCE, which was approximately January that year)
We also know that Herod’s first year of reign from his conquest of Jerusalem is counted ex post facto to the spring of 37 BCE, as evidenced by his seventh year falling in the spring of 31 BCE (Joseph BJ 1.370). Despite any counting methods that may be employed, whether Nisan to Nisan, Tishri to Tishri, or even January to January, it holds true nonetheless that Josephus’ regnal counting methodology concludes that the spring of 31 BCE coincides with Herod’s seventh year of reign. If the spring of 31 BCE falls in his seventh year, then, cyclically, the spring of 32 BCE falls in his sixth year, the spring of 33 BCE in his fifth year, and so on, causing the spring of 37 BCE to be his first year by default. Consequently, counting forward from these directly stated regnal years and datable events shows that the spring of 1 BCE would align with his thirty-seventh year of reign from his capture of Jerusalem, with thirty-six years of completed reign, making the total regnal count by the parallel thirty-nine and thirty-six years of reign at the time of his death, or forty and thirty-seven if counted with whole calendar years after the fashion of the 4 BCE advocates.
Concerning Herod’s reign from his Roman appointment, the fourth year coincides with the first year of his conquest of Jerusalem. Therefore, the regnal parallel, independent of other facts, autonomously substantiates Herod’s fourth year as falling in the spring of 37 BCE. Furthermore, the month of Shebat in the winter of 37 BCE, deductively, is said to be Herod’s third year, whereas Sivan of 37 BCE is his fourth year by the regnal parallel, corroborating not only the chronological correctness of his fourth year in 37 BCE, but also the regnal transition on the 1st of Nisan, as opposed to Tishri or January. (Joseph. AJ 14.465. The new Roman year would have begun in the Hebrew month Tebeth. If Herod’s regnal years advanced on January 1st as some suggest, he would have already been in his fourth year when the siege of Jerusalem began in Shebat.) With Herod’s fourth year from the time the Romans declared him king established as being parallel to the spring of 37 BCE, which is the first year from the time he captured Jerusalem, his first year of reign from the time the Romans declared him king should be counted from 40 BCE, reckoned ex post facto to the spring of that year according to Jewish practice. (bRosh Hash. 2a)
All things considered, the facts are in perfect agreement with the other parts of Josephus’ narrative, who tells us that Herod was made king by the Romans in the 184th Olympiad, in the year when Caius Domithis Calvinus was consul for the second time and Caius Asinius Pollio for the first time, and that he captured Jerusalem in 37 BCE, in the 185th Olympiad, when Marcus Agrippa and Caninius Gallus were the consuls at Rome. (Joseph. AJ 14.337, 389, 14.487-8, 17.191; Joseph BJ 1.253-4, 1.665)
In short, Herod’s parallel reigns, beyond any question or ambiguity, began in 40 BCE and 37 BCE respectively, as is further corroborated by other datable events (Joseph. AJ 15.121, 15.317, 15.299, 302, 15.354; Joseph. BJ 1.370; Dio Cass. 50.4, 50.10.1, 50.11-15, 50.31.6, 51.1.1, 53.28.1, 53.29.3-8, 54.7.4-6; Fasti Amiternini and Fasti Antiates Ministrorum, Inscr. Ital. 13.1 132.26; Vell. Pat. 2.84.1. Parallels to Herod’s reign include the battle of Actium in 31 BCE, the expedition into Arabia-Felix in 24 BCE, and Caesar coming into Syria in 20 BCE). In which case, his death in 1 BCE is an impossible argument. A total reign of thirty-seven and thirty-four years from 40 BCE and 37 BCE, no matter how ingenuously one attempts to count it, simply cannot equate to 1 BCE by any stretch of the imagination. Early 2 BCE is the closest that can be accomplished, though it requires using accession years and interval counting methods, which are both improper for counting Jewish regnal years and cause dating inconsistencies with other events when employed. With Herod’s third year from his Roman appointment being in the winter of 38/37 BCE, and his seventh year from his conquest of Jerusalem falling in the spring of 31 BCE, an accession year method of counting is blatantly incorrect, as is interval counting if one knows anything at all about the regnal counting methods of that era.
That said, the 1 BCE hypothesis should be altogether dismissed and permanently retired from further credible discussion.
Concerning 31 CE for the crucifixion:
We have at least three known Passovers listed in the gospels. The first is in John, and relative to the context of Jesus' forty days in the wilderness, which do not occur in John, John's context is clearly well after Jesus' baptism. This first Passover listed is therefore the following year, or the sixteenth year of Tiberius. John lists a second one in 6:4, which, assuming it's chronological, would be the seventeenth year of Tiberius. Then there is the known final Passover when he was crucified, which would be, at the minimum, the eighteenth year of Tiberius.
If Tiberius' fifteenth year of reign was 29 CE, 32 CE is the earliest the crucifixion could have occurred. A fourth Passover can be potentially extrapolated from the gospel text. But these three are definitively stated. Furthermore, only the years 33 CE and 34 CE meet the criteria for the day and date of the crucifixion, depending on one's interpretation of the Hebrew date.
I hope some of this information gives you clarity about some of the things that have caused your confusion. There are a lot of hypotheses out there. But there aren't many who have done the sincere research on the subject. Herod didn't die in 1 BCE. Jesus wasn't crucified in 31 CE. And he didn't die on a Wednesday.

Hi Alex,  I know you have done a ton of work on the history.  are you saying the crucifixion happened on 15th Nisan? 15th was always a day of rest.

It would be great if you would comment directly on Andrew Steinmann's work "From Abraham to Paul", especially p219-254 to get to the bottom of who is correct. The 37bc date you quote he argues has conflicting evidence and could and should from other evidence be read as 36bc.

@AndrewShanks, the "conflicting evidence" between 37 and 36 BCE, to be blunt, is due to poor research. I don't mind reading it if you have a link, but I have no honest need to do so. I am confident that it's all the same arguments made by Ernest Martin, W. E. Filmer, and others. Arguments, for example, about the sabbatical year not aligning with the Maccabean period, etc. But a more thorough analysis of these arguments shows that they are subjective and incorrect. Confirmation bias. They see what they want to see.

@AndrewShanks, I found it on Internet Archive. I was right. It's just the same regurgitated arguments. What he wrote is hardly unique or original. A great number of the arguments focus on 1 Maccabees, where a careful examination would show that the author is using Jewish regnal years. All of the 1 Maccabees dates are a year higher than 2 Maccabees. When you break down the chronology of Simon in 1 Maccabees, you'll see that the dates don't match unless you reckon them in a Jewish regnal year format. There isn't room in these notes to elaborate sufficiently, but this is the fact of the matter.

@AFrazier you said "The 16th was only a sabbath if it fell on a Saturday."  Is this a general statement or one regarding the 15th on that particular Friday?  IOW, is the 16th not always considered a Sabbath by some, regardless of the day (like Saturday) it fell?

@SLM. The 15th of Nisan, in the first century, was considered a sabbath of the holiday variety, regardless of what day it fell on. The 16th of Nisan was not considered a sabbath relative to the specific date or day of the festival. The only time the 16th was a sabbath was when it happened to fall on a Saturday. Did I communicate that adequately (no sarcasm intended)?

Yes, thank you.  The reason for the question was some believe the 16th is first fruits per Num 28:26 is a sabbath.

@SLM, the 16th is first fruits and the official start for the count to Pentecost. The Scholion to the Megalit ta'anit indicate that this was a dispute between the Pharisees and the Sadducees, whether the sabbath in the "morrow after the sabbath" meant the weekly sabbath or the holiday sabbath. The Pharisees won the argument, so to speak, so that the 15th was considered the "sabbath" after which first fruits were offered and the count to Pentecost began. The Talmud confirms this, and so does Josephus, who was himself a contemporary of the time and plainly says that the count is from the 16th.

Yes, a dispute on starting the count with Masoretic translated day after weekly Sabbath, while Septuagint (Philo and Josephus) translated as day after Feast (first day of Unleavened Bread on 15th) Sabbath.  FWIW, it is clear at Lev 23:15 that the two texts agree (And ye shall number to yourselves from the day after the [weekly] sabbath, from the day [the 16th after the Feast sabbath] on which ye shall offer the sheaf of the heave-offering, seven full weeks: )  IOW, first fruits was on the 16th, but the count begins after the weekly sabbath after the 16th.  Anyway, appreciate it.
